# Are "subject" and "object" syntactic classifications?

Tags: subjects, argument-structure

I would like to know where the classification of Arguments such as *subject*, *object*... comes from. I know that the roles classifications come from *Thematic roles*; however, how about those mentioned above?

I looked into both terms but couldn't find any reference pointing where they derive from.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are syntactic terms.

You asked where they derive from.  The OED's etymology of **subject** says, in part:

> post-classical Latin *subiectum* (neuter) topic, theme, (in philosophy) central substance or core of a thing as opposed to its attributes (4th cent.), (in grammar) part of a sentence of which the rest of the sentence is predicated (5th cent.), uses as noun of past participle of classical Latin *subicere*.

[Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=subicio) tells us (under *subicio*):

> In the later philos. and gram. lang.: **subjec-tum** , *i, n.* (*sc. verbum*), that which is spoken of, the foundation or subject of a proposition

While the "subiectum" comes from "subicio" *throw under*, "obiectum" is from "obicio" *throw towards*.

Although English takes most its grammatical terminology from Latin, a lot of the concepts originated in ancient Greece but under different names: for example, Aristotle [referred](http://ethicalpolitics.org/ablunden/works/aristotle.htm) to the "subject" as ὑποκείμενον *hypokeimenon*, which literally means "underlying thing" - though his use of the term may have been less exact than the modern definition (see below).

According to Els Elffers-van Ketel, *The Historiography of Grammatical Concepts* (1991):

> In an indirect way subject and predicate reach back to Plato and Aristotle.  Expositions about the notions often present a rather complicated narrative about various pairs of notions, 'ousia-symbekos' ('substance-quality'), 'hypokeimenon-kategoroumenon' ('underlying element-statement') and 'onoma-rhema' ('noun-verb'), which were fused into one, and became, in variable degree and proportion, elements of the many variants of the pair 'subject-predicate'...
>
> The terms "subiectum" and "praedicatum" are mostly thought to be introduced into logic by Boethius as a translation of "hypokeimenon" and "kategoroumenon" around A.D. 500, but Pfister mentions the use of these terms a hundred years earlier by Martianus Capella.  Subiectum and praedicatum entered grammar in the late Middle Ages, but as grammatical notions they remained rather obscure for a long time... Only in the 18th century... did the notions obtain their central position in grammar.

Comment: rjpond, it is still unclear to me; according to Els Elffers-van Ketel: *"The terms "subiectum" and "praedicatum" are mostly thought to be introduced into logic by Boethius as a translation of "hypokeimenon" and "kategoroumenon" around A.D. 500"*, if it is thought to be introducted into logic, shouldn't it be a semantic classification? Why exactly does it have a syntactic classification? Due to its placement?

Comment: The terms "subject" and "predicate" are still today used by logicians, but this doesn't stop them also being used by linguists, and the definition of them as grammatical terms is not identical, though clearly related.  These terms are clearly used widely in works on grammar and syntax.  I don't think they can be defined semantically, because in passive and impersonal constructions, the grammatical subject isn't the same thing as the semantic "doer" of the action.

Comment: Formal logic has a syntax; without that you could not write logical propositions in it.